# make "Close" button outside of a div

Tags: html, css

I have login button that is getting a little bit outside of the border of a div, but when I try to make it the same in the code it doesn't work.

```
.closeWindow{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px; /* width of the close button / 2 */
    margin-bottom: 15px; /* height of the close button / 2 */
}
```

Where I want it to be placed (The little image close-button):
[image: where it supposed to be placed]

Where it actually placed:
[image: where it actually placed, using the css code that I wrote.]

Comment: We'll need to see the full code example, however the basic answer is to use positioning to move it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do not use float

instead in your container div use

```
position :relative;
```

and in the close box div use these styles

```
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
right: -15px;
```

(given the fact that if your close button is 30x30)

Answer (score 2):

change the margin to a minus for example margin-left:-20px;. this will make the element move 20px to the right.

```
margin-left: -40px;  /*moves 40px right*/
margin-bottom: -20px; /*moves 20px up*/
```

This problem occured once with me and the best way to fix it is by using negative margins.

or you can use absolute positioning.

```
position:absolute;
left:value;
top:value;
```